# Python: Printing cells from Excel based on their value

Tags: python, excel

I want to print some cells from Excel based on the value based on their value. For the most part it is working, but getting an error at the end. Here's what I have so far...

**this has now been resolved, the working script is below**

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import time, pythoncom

xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add(r'X:\HR & IT\IT\LOGS\Dynamics Idle Sessions\Copy of Dynamics Idle Sessions.xlsm')
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
xl.Run('Refresh')
time.sleep(0.5)

idlerow = 6

while idlerow < 32:
    idletime = ws.Cells(idlerow,3).value
    user = ws.Cells(idlerow,4).value
    if idletime is not None:
        if idletime > 60 and len(user) > 6:
            print(user,'\thas been logged on to Dynamics for\t',idletime,'\tminutes.')
        elif idletime > 60 and len(user) <= 6:
            print(user,'\t\thas been logged on to Dynamics for\t',idletime,'\tminutes.')
    idlerow += 1

xl.Quit()
pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```

The error I'm getting:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:/HR & IT/Ryan/Python Scripts/DynamicsUsersMT60.py", line 15, in <module>
    if idletime > 60 and len(user) > 6:
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()"
```

If I set idletime as an int I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:/HR & IT/Ryan/Python Scripts/DynamicsUsersMT60.py", line 13, in <module>
    idletime = int(ws.Cells(idlerow,3).value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

These errors will only come up **after** the script appears to have run correctly and printed what I need. Little help please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the value of `idletime` becomes `None`, add an additional check:

```
if idletime is not None:
    if idletime > 60 and len(user) > 6:
        print(user,'\thas been logged on to Dynamics for\t',idletime,'\tminutes.')
    elif idletime > 60 and len(user) <= 6:
        print(user,'\t\thas been logged on to Dynamics for\t',idletime,'\tminutes.')
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's worked. I can't accept the answer yet I will do so in 8 minutes!